# Calling a model in a Helper file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to write a function for loading dropdown in helper file and for that reason I want to Use my models in Helper file.

When I use this it give me the error:

```
$this->load->model("news_model");
```

The Error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\test\application\helpers\component_helper.php on line 6
```

my method:

```
function dropdown($Class,$Attribute)
{
$Output=NULL;
$ClassName=$Class."_model";
$this->load->model($ClassName);
$FullData=$ClassName->get();
foreach ($FullData as $Data) 
{
    $Output.='<option value="'.$Data->Id.'">'.$Data->$Attribute.'</option>';
}
return $Output;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is line 6 referring to $this->load->model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this post:

```
function my_helper()
{
    // Get a reference to the controller object
    //$CI = get_instance();
    // use this below
    $CI = &get_instance();

    // You may need to load the model if it hasn't been pre-loaded
    $CI->load->model('my_model');

    // Call a function of the model
    $CI->my_model->do_something();
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2479485/1570901

Comment: When I use $CI = getInstance(); It gives me error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getInstance() in C:\xampp\test\application\helpers\component_helper.php on line 6

Comment: It is $CI = get_instance(); NOT: getInstance();

Answer (score 3):

Helper functions are *functions*. This means they are not bound to an object nor class. `$this` is therefor not avaible!

You have to get the instance of CodeIgniter-Core from somewhere else!

CodeIgniter provides a `get_instance();` function for that:

```
$CI = get_instance();
```

Now wereever you had `$this->load` etc.
Replace `$this` with `$CI` to call on the CodeIgniter Core!

And by the way you are calling the model wrong. You have to access it via the CI-core:

```
 $CI->$Classname->get();
```

Comment: When I use $CI = getInstance(); It gives me error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getInstance() in C:\xampp\test\application\helpers\component_helper.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correction for you code:

```
function dropdown($Class,$Attribute)
{
$CI = get_instance();
$Output=NULL;
$ClassName=$Class."_model";
$CI->load->model($ClassName);
$FullData=$ClassName->get();
foreach ($FullData as $Data) 
{
    $Output.='<option value="'.$Data->Id.'">'.$Data->$Attribute.'</option>';
}
return $Output;
}
```

Now instead of using $this, always use $CI inside this method.

Hope this helps.