# Get username from userid in a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, tableadapter

I am getting data from a table and showing in my view (codeigniter). In the view I have user id which is of course an integer. I need to get username from user id. How i will get the username from id ?

Model code is below .

```
class Resumemodel extends CI_Model
{
   function getallresume()
  {
     $query = $this->db->get('resume');
        return $query;
  }
}
```

Controller code is below.

```
class Resumec extends CI_Controller 
{
  function resumelist()
  {
    $this->load->model('Resumemodel');
    $query = $this->Resumemodel->getallresume();
    $dt['main_content'] = 'admin/resumeinfo';   
    $dt['query'] = $query;
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/template.php',$dt);
  }
 }
```

view is below (only required part i put here)

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $id = $row->user_id;
   // other table data.
 }
```

So from user id how i will get user name without join Query ?

PS **Please provide answer without join query. It will work with join query, but I am looking for alternatives.**

I tried with this-

```
 $objResume = new resumec();  //resumec is the controller
 $username = $objResume->get_username($id); // get_username is function to get username.
 echo $username;
```

This is working but this is not proper / good way according to MVC logic. So is there any alternatives ?

edit - 2 tables are there. 'user' and 'resume'. user_id is in 'resume' table and uid, username is in 'user' table.

Comment: Where is the username located in your database? How is the data structured - user id and username are on two separate tables?

Comment: @Daniel Edited my question. Check it plz. Added table info in the last part of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read about Codeigniter helpers**

Simply just extend the helper to include the function that get username by id.

To gain more knowledge, just visit [Codeigniter helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Good Luck

Comment: ohh.. yes. I am already using a helper function to link my css and js files. So I know how to use helpers.. but in helper I have to write basic database queries. Right ?

Comment: No you don't need too, simply load model into it, and use it's method.

Comment: Check this answer to load model into helpers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479132/how-can-i-load-model-to-helper

Comment: yes, this is working. Thank you. +1 for the link which is a global answer, not just for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this changes:

```
class Resumec extends CI_Controller 
{
  function resumelist()
  {
    $this->load->model('Resumemodel');
    $query = $this->Resumemodel->getallresume();
    $usernames = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
      $usernames[$row->user_id] = $this->get_username($row->user_id);
    }
    $dt['main_content'] = 'admin/resumeinfo';
    $dt['query'] = $query;
    $dt['usernames'] = $usernames;
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/template.php',$dt);
  }
 }
```

So, into the view you just do this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $id = $row->user_id;
   $username = $usernames[$row->user_id];
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is also working. But unfortunately I cannot mark 2 answers as accepted answer. But still +1 (upvote) for your time and effort. I checked this too. and this is working. :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like `Resumemodel` you may/should have Usermodel where you can define function `get_user_name($user_id)`.
You can load this model along with `Resumemodel` and can use `get_user_name` function wherever you want.